# Как парсить похожие JSON в котором меняются имена ключей C#

Tags: c#, json, парсер

есть два json файла которые по своей структуре одинаковы, но в одном из них в одной ветке отличаются названия ключей. Мне не нужна информация которая там храниться, но из-за неправильных названий классов парсит неправильно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть ключи в ветке qm разные. Как быть?

Comment: `Мне не нужна информация которая там храниться` - ну так не десериализуйте этот участок, любой десериализатор позволяет не создавать полный макет JSON, а лишь определенные свойства и это не повлияет как либо на работу десериализации.

Comment: Просто удалите часть свойств в модели, данные в которых не нужны.